# Objective C frontend- Java/C# backend

Tags: c#, java, objective-c, c, xml

I need to build a backend for an iPad app done in Objective C. I have two choices for that, one being Java and other C#.
With a backend built in either one of those, what options do I have to put the backend and frontend together? One option could be to use XML messaging. What are the other options?

Also what is the standard way of doing this? i.e. if we have an objective C frontend, then what should the backend be in and what communication mechanism should be used between the two?

I did some reasearch and am sure that either of Java or C# would work, but I could not find much information on how to make them work with the frontend? (Please bear in mind someone else would be doing the frontend)

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question and move it to programmers.stackexchange.com instead. This cannot be objectively answered here. There are so many types of communication protocols any useful answers would be hard to find. That said, I have been preferring JSON as a message protocol over xml lately. It's compact and doesn't require the plethora of external libraries to process.

Comment: Agreed, especially when it comes to JSON over XML.

Comment: @Andrew. Thanks for your comment, all I am looking for is if someone could possibly list a few of those protocols, let’s say there are four protocols that could be used (a, b, c and d) and then say that ‘b’ is the industry standard these days. I'll take it from there. (will look at the website you recommended, thanks again)

Comment: There is no 'industry standard' when it comes to server integration for Objective C applications. JSON is the preferred communication format and currently, [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is the fastest framework for consuming it. Note that as of IOS5 JSON can also be processed using base SDK classes. JSONKit is faster though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few things to consider. Wire protocol and Message protocol.

Wire Protocol:

This will contains things like the Message Id, Sender, Subject, Type, Timestamp, Message Size, etc. This is just as important as the Message Protocol. In order to recommend a Wire protocol I'd need to know more about your system. If you want a simple Wire protocol that will work on all those platforms you can take a look at STOMP. It is a simple ASCII based protocol for transmitting messages. It can be useful for debugging messages etc. ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ are Brokering systems that supports STOMP. I prefer RabbitMQ.

Simple STOMP message:

```
SEND
destination:/queue/a
content-type:text/plain

hello queue a
^@
```

You can also use HTTP as a simple wire protocol. It is simple and ASCII based like STOMP. Plus  SOAP typically uses HTTP as it's transport protocol. SOAP also typically uses XML for it's message format to encode the Envelop, header and body of a message.

There is also JSON-RPC.

Message Format:

Most of the information in the Wire Protocol is used to determine where the message goes, if it got there, what type of information is in the message etc. Generally it is only used by the messaging system you put in place to send and receive messages. What your business logic is interested in, is the message content itself. You need a way to encode that content that both sides understand. There are plenty of choices for this: JSON, XML, Google's protobuf (binary).

I would have a hard time recommending any of these without more knowledge of what you need to do. They each have their own strengths and weaknesses.

Real-world mapping for wire and message protocols:

UPS, US Postal, FedEx = wire protocol
letter from mom, loan application, birthday card = message

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for. I'll explore the three (JSON, XML, Google's protobuf) to see which one works best for me.